# Can you write an extension into the email / messaging app?

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

Is it possible to "plug-in" or create an extension to the email app on Windows Phone?  The way the user would interact with it is that during the creation or reading of a message my tool would be another option on the New or Read message command bar?  Essentially I would like to extend the functionality of the mail app.  I don't see any other way at this point other than creating a brand new email application for the phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The best you can do is to use the share contract in your application and send some information to the Email app. Once it opens up, you won't be able to "plug" any behavior.

Have a look in [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/Hh871373%28v=win.10%29.aspx) and [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/windows.applicationmodel.email.aspx) MSDN articles.

Comment: thanks for the answer, the links you provided for references both come up as ERROR on MSDN and Windows Phone Dev Center while attempting to visit.  -update links might be viable still...looks like MSDN is having link issues.